# Replace color of a dye in player's inventory with another

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to replace a dye in player's inventory with a new dye, of a different color, for example from cyan to gray.

My plugin changes one dye to another perfectly, but when I move it to my hotbar, I can't drop it and when I click on it in my inventory, it suddenly disappears. In that case I suppose the item does not exist.

How can I change the color of this item?

---

#### Code:

```
Dye dye = new Dye();
dye.setColor(DyeColor.RED);
  ItemStack dye4 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye4.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.ORANGE);
  ItemStack dye3 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye4.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.PURPLE);
  ItemStack dye2 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye4.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.CYAN);
  ItemStack dye1 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye4.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.GRAY);
  ItemStack dye0 = dye.toItemStack();
 
ArrayList<ItemStack> dyes = new ArrayList<ItemStack>(Arrays.asList(
  dye0, dye1, dye2, dye3, dye4
));

p.getOpenInventory().getTopInventory().setItem(1, dyes.get(0));
```

*Note: I've shortened my code for this example.*

---

#### Screenshots:

*Before*

[image: Before]

*After*

[image: After]

*I moved it to hotbar - a second before it disappeared (because I didn't click on it :D)​*

[image: I moved it to hotbar - a second before it disappeared (because I didn't click on it :D)​]

---

#### Download

I made an example plugin with this error:

- [Main file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PDKnight/pdknight.github.io/master/bukkit-error-plugin/awd.java)
- [Example plugin to download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/763mim1jhliypin/AWD.jar?dl=1)

---

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I also used `p.updateInventory();`, but without any visible result :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a stupid bug in my code, I didn't set amount of the gray dye to 1.

#### Final code

```
Dye dye = new Dye();
dye.setColor(DyeColor.RED);
  ItemStack dye4 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye4.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.ORANGE);
  ItemStack dye3 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye3.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.PURPLE);
  ItemStack dye2 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye2.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.CYAN);
  ItemStack dye1 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye1.setAmount(1);
dye.setColor(DyeColor.GRAY);
  ItemStack dye0 = dye.toItemStack();
  dye0.setAmount(1);

ImmutableList<ItemStack> dyes 
  = ImmutableList.of(dye0, dye1, dye2, dye3, dye4);

p.getOpenInventory().getTopInventory().setItem(1, dyes.get(0));
```

Comment: Since Bukkit has that dependency attached in runtime anyway, just use `ImmutableList.of(dye0, dye1, dye2, dye3, dye4)`.

Comment: @Unihedron great, so I can get the right dye from this _ImmutableList_ like `dyes.get(index);`?

Comment: @PDKnight: What tells you otherwise?

Comment: @Unihedron I tested it and it seems like I have to cast the returned Object to ItemStack. Can't wait for the next test of the plugin :P

Comment: `ImmutableList<ItemStack> dyes = ImmutableList.of(); dyes.get(index)` should work.